# Is it possible to run more than one app under same virtual environment in django

Tags: python, django

I am stuck when I want to add a field in model.py of accounts app. Here is my code

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

   class User(AbstractUser):
     pp = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
     xx = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

When I run migration command it shows
"Table 'auth_permission' already exists")
But If I want to add a field in question table under polls app it works fine.

mysite is the main folder. polls and accounts are two apps inside it.
I created polls app first.
Can I run two apps and codes under same virtual environment and using same database??
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking 2 different questions: multiple apps and customized user model.

Ok, first things first! **Running multiple Django apps** is not only possible but the correct thing to do to separate logical instances (i.e. one app for customers, one for products etc)

Substituting the user model is actually the recommended way to go according to the Django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-user-model).

I usually add the 'custom user' folder under my main app, if that is *mysite*, then that's where I would add it. 
Make sure it's executable with the neccessary `__init__.py` file in it.
If you like to have it in a different app, that's fine too. Make sure that app is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` then.

In that case you could add to your settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

To access the User model anywhere in your code, Django recommends to use this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

Changing the user model mid-project is a different animal entirely. Please see here for Django's concerns on that (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project)

So in other words: if you want to go with a customized user model, **do it at the project start**!

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you have to respect when creating a custum user model.

You might make yourself familiar with the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) about it

a few things to highlight:

```
#settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customauth.User'
```

After making changes run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```